# Operation not supported on socket @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, jekyll, osx-yosemite

I upgraded my mac o/s to Yosemite.

After the upgrade I tried to work on a project that is a jekyll site. I ran `jekyll serve`, and received the following error:

```
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Operation not supported on socket @ rb_sysopen
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Where are you running the server from? What is the folder? Is it the root directory for the project?

Comment: Yes. It is the root directory for the project.

Comment: Do you have some more stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I got this solved by removing `runctl` file from the base directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

> jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  Operation not supported on socket @ rb_sysopen - /Users/fanybo/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/App Shim Socket

I was running the server on the root directory, then I changed the directory, and changed the browser, now it works!